# Склонение сочетания «дельфин афалина»

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, склонение, род

*Ученые обнаружили дельфина афалину.* Или дельфина афалины?
Как правильно? Склоняюсь к первому варианту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректный вариант: ***Ученый обнаружили дельфина афалину.***

Пояснение:

Дельфин – м.род, афалина – ж.род.

При наличии **родового названия**  «афалина» в научных описаниях  чаще не склоняется, например: описание и особенности дельфина Афалина (Р.п.), питание дельфина  Афалина (Р.п.).

Но текстах общего характера  падежное согласование возможно: обнаружили дельфина афалину (В.п.)

При отсутствии родового названия  видовое название склоняется,  например, такая фраза: О том, как их песик поиграл с афалиной, мы писали здесь.

**Для справок:**

Афали́на, или большо́й дельфи́н, или бутылконо́сый дельфи́н — вид дельфинов.

Дельфиновые – это  семейство морских млекопитающих из первотряда зубатых китов, другое название – океанические дельфины.   Род и вид  – афалины, но существуют разные  подвиды: Черноморская афалина, Дальневосточная афалина, Индийская афалина.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

У дельфинов сложная классификация, в разных источниках излагается по-разному. Есть семейство Дельфиновые, оно делится на роды, виды и подвиды.

СЕМЕЙСТВО ДЕЛЬФИНОВЫХ. Данное семейство объединяет множество родов и видов морских дельфинов.

1. АФАЛИНЫ  (из видов этого рода самый известный – атлантическая, или просто афалина (T. truncatus), широко распространенная в теплых водах всего мира.
2. ДЕЛЬФИН-БЕЛОБОЧКА (из рода обыкновенных дельфинов – один из наиболее распространенных в Средиземном море представителей семейств).  В отличие от других эти дельфины очень стройные, с длинным клювом. И еще несколько малоизвестных родов.

Таким образом, афалина – это название и рода, и вида, а дельфин-белобочка – это другой род. Таковы традиционные названия этих морских животных.

https://www.krugosvet.ru/enc/nauka_i_tehnika/biologiya/DELFINI.html

Comment: *Sharon*, приветствую. А разве нужно писать "Афалина" с прописной? *Описание и особенности дельфина Афалина, питание дельфина Афалина.* Возникает ощущение, что *Афалин* — это фамилия. Сравните: дельфин Коммерсона, дельфин Хевисайда, дельфин Гектора (самый маленький).

Comment: Добрый день, Римма. С прописной буквы пишутся все официальные названия, а в научно-популярной литературе чаще используется строчная буква.

Answer (score 1):

> В предложении: «Ученый обнаружили дельфина афалину или дельфина
> афалины». Как склонять? Склоняюсь к первому варианту.

Более правилен третий вариант – с дефисным написанием (и со склонением обеих частей сложного слова):

*…обнаружили **дельфина-афалину.***

См. **«Русский орфографический словарь»:**

> **дельфин-афалина**, дельфин**а**-афалин**ы**, *м.*
>
> [http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=дельфин-афалина](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Один из примеров использования дефисного написания биологами:

> *Межполушарные отношения в цикле сон-бодрствование **дельфинов-афалин**.*
>
> http://www.dslib.net/fiziologia--p-106.html

Comment: А океанические дельфины вроде бы все афалины. Интересно,  составители словаря с биологами консультировались? Да и текст странный: где же они его обнаружили? И как выглядит этот дельфин-афалина, чем он от обычного дельфина  отличается?

Comment: Кстати, по Розенталю через дефис писались сложные видовые названия (рыба-пила, жук-олень).  Теперь будем писать рыба-окунь тоже через дефис?  А раньше было: рыба-окунь или окунь-рыба.